# Issue on implementing local notifications in ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, angular5, localnotification

I am trying to add notifications to my app but it seems that nothing is working. 
I have added the imports in the app module as well as in the page I am implementing the notification .I expected to see notification but after clicking the button nothing is appearing.

```js
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';

   play(){
       this.localNotifications.schedule({
                id: 1,
                text: 'Hello there',
                data: 'notified'
        });
   }
```

**Code for the button:**

```
  <button class="login-button" ion-button round color="secondary"(click)="play()">NOTIFICATION</button>
```

Comment: are you testing this on native device? or via ionic serve?

Comment: @Sergey Rudenko , I am using a real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you install and configure properly, try the below steps

**Step # 1**
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification
    npm install @ionic-native/local-notifications

**Step # 2**
You will also need to add the plugin as a provider in **src/app/app.module.ts**

```
 providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    LocalNotifications,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

May be you forget to add in app.module

**Step # 3**

```
Import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';


constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) { }

...


// Schedule a single notification
this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: 1,
  text: 'Single ILocalNotification',
  sound: isAndroid? 'file://sound.mp3': 'file://beep.caf',
  data: { secret: key }
});
```